# How to change disk setting 'thick lazy zeroed' to 'eager zeroed thick' by command line (Linux) or API (pyvmomi) from outside of an ESX?

Tags: python, vmware-vsphere, ansible

I use Ansible 2.6 and pyvmomi 6.7.0 to create some vm via vSphere 6.0.0.

When I resize disk, I loose 'eager zeroed thick' disk setting.

What is the simplest way to get back to this setting remotly (not from esx server) via API or a Linux command line ?

I prefer another solution than ssh to esx server, then using 'vmkfstool -d zeroedthick...'

Comment: Try storage vmotion.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-Place storage vmotion with the disk type set your desired disk type should do the trick, according to [VMware's KB entry](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2014832).

Doing it with the API should be possible as well, see the [pyvmomi sample for vmotion](https://github.com/rreubenur/vmware-pyvmomi-examples/blob/master/vmotion.py) and VMware's API docs [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsan.apiref.doc%2Fvim.vm.RelocateSpec.html) and [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsan.apiref.doc%2Fvim.vm.RelocateSpec.html).

It does sound like a bug in ansible's `vmware_guest` (which I assume you are using). I suggest bringing this to the attention of the ansible devs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it :

### From esx

```
vmkfstools -X 25G -d eagerzeroedthick  /vmfs/volumes/FOOBAR/FOOBAR.vmdk
```

### From remote Linux box with `vmware-vcli` :

```
vmkfstools --datacenter x --vihost esx42 --server vc1.example.com --username me \
-X 25G -d eagerzeroedthick  /vmfs/volumes/FOOBAR/FOOBAR.vmdk
```

To update the VmWare inventory, you need to run :

```
svmotion --datastore foobar --server vc1.example.com --username me \
--interactive
```